# What does a friendly and enemy Reaper say when teleporting?

Tags: overwatch

I've noticed that Reaper will say lines after completing a teleport, like

1. "Death comes..."
2. "Re-positioning..."
3. "From the shadows..."

Do the lines change depending on whether or not a friendly or enemy Reaper is teleporting nearby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I've been able to tell, there is no voice line at all for friendly Reapers teleporting. Even when standing a few meters away from a friendly Reaper's teleport destination, the only sound made was the teleport noise.

On the other hand, an enemy Reaper teleporting nearby, even hidden from sight, will play one of those voice lines at moderately high volume (think of Tracer's voice lines when activating Recall, you can hear those clearly even as an enemy), warning you of the incoming danger.

Answer (score -5):

Ultimates are the only abilities with team-specific voicelines.

Comment: I imagine this is downvoted because it's simply false.